# Twitter to Facebook connection is not working

Tags: facebook, twitter

I'm trying to connect a Twitter account to a Facebook one.

I have connected the Facebook account from [App Settings](https://twitter.com/settings/applications) in Twitter and Authorized Twitter Application.

However, Tweets are not being posted to the Facebook account, and every time I visit the App Settings page in Twitter, I find that the Facebook account is disconnected.

I tried to disconnect both Facebook and Twitter, clear cache, restart browser and try reconnecting again (as mentioned in [Twitter Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170742-facebook)), but it is still not working.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Check your profile to make sure you've connected the two correctly. It should say `"Your account is connected to Facebook."`

Comment: It does say `"Your account is connected to Facebook"` but once I refresh the page it disconnects!

Comment: I have the same problem, but it does not "auto-disconnect" and it stays always connected, also after login/logout.. problem is only that it does not post on facebook profile!! please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with cookies, deleting all the cookies, clearing the cache, and restarting the browser solved the problem!

Comment: No, it didn't solve the problem, as of now :(

Answer (score 3):

A recent update to the Facebook Platform Policies ended the ability to automatically post Tweets to your Facebook profile or page. https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/link-twitter-to-facebook?lang=browser

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to link `Twitter` to `Facebook`:

- Log in to Twitter.
- Click on the wheel on the top right of your homepage.
- Select "Settings".
- Select "Profile".
- Select "Connect to Facebook". Once you select it, you will open a new browser to continue the process.
- Click on "Log in With Facebook".
- Log in to Facebook. If your Facebook is already open, you won't have to complete this step. Next, Twitter will ask for permission to post on your behalf.
- Click on "Allow" to accept permissions. Your tweets will now automatically be posted on Facebook and your username will show up on Facebook as well. Replies won't be posted.
  => Check the bottom of your profile to make sure you've connected the two correctly. It should say "Your account is connected to Facebook."
- Adjust your settings if necessary. Twitter will be set for posting your retweets to Facebook, and for posting to your Facebook profile. If you don't want those things to happen, then unclick the clicked boxes next to these items.

Try above steps. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but I already did that exactly! My problem is that it keeps disconnecting once I leave the page!

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue. I guess you have tried doing and undoing the Facebook - Twitter connection several times, as I did. The only explanation I have seen so far is that it may take some time for Twitter to undo previous Facebook connections as they stated [here](https://support.twitter.com/articles/31113):

> If you disconnect your Facebook account from Twitter, we will delete the Facebook account information that you previously authorized. Please note that it may take up to a few weeks for this information to be fully removed from our systems.

Guess I'd try again in a week or so.

Comment: I answered my question :)
You just need to delete all the cookies and clear the cache!